# How to properly deal with optional parameter

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm using Typescript and I want to write a function with an optional parameter. I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, because there is no issue, but it is about writing clean code:

```
public addResource(config?: ResourceConfig): void {
  if (!config) {
    config = {} as ResourceConfig;
  }
  const resource: FormGroup = this.createResource(config); 
  this.control.push(resource);
}

private createResource({ amount, profit, load }: ResourceConfig): FormGroup {
  return new FormGroup({
    amount: new FormControl(amount || 1),
    profit: new FormControl(profit || 1),
    load: new FormControl(load || 1)
  });
}

...

interface ResourceConfig {
  amount: number;
  profit: number;
  load: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you're using the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option, and if you're not then you should.

---

I think the optional parameter itself is not a problem, but from your usage it seems like you expect that the individual properties of the `ResourceConfig` objects passed to `addResource()` and `createResource()` might be missing.  But the signatures of those methods do not say that.  This sets up a situation where you have to try to sidestep TypeScript's type system instead of working with it.

Specifically, the line `config = {} as ResourceConfig;` is problematic.  You've essentially lied to the compiler using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), because the empty object `{}` is not a `ResourceConfig`.  Sometimes little white lies to the compiler are useful, especially if they are only temporary (if, for example, after that line you went on to set all the properties in an initially empty object).  But in this case you never populate the properties of `config`, so the deception passes into the `createResource()` method... where the `amount`, `profit`, and `load` variables are thought by the compiler to be `number` but are in fact possibly `undefined` at run time.  You deal with this possibility by checking each value for [falsiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/falsy), but it looks to be unnecessary if I believe the type system.

---

There are different ways to handle this.  One is to just say that it's okay if `config` is missing some properties.  That implies that instead of dealing with `ResourceConfig` you really have `Partial<ResourceConfig>`, where `Partial<T>` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) in the standard library whose [definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.0.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1351-L1356) is

```
type Partial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] };
```

so `Partial<ResourceConfig>` is equivalent to

```
{
  amount?: number;
  profit?: number;
  load?: number;
}
```

Using that instead, you get:

```
public addResource(config?: Partial<ResourceConfig>): void {
  if (!config) {
    config = {}; // truth
  }
  const resource: FormGroup = this.createResource(config);
  this.control.push(resource);
}

private createResource({ amount, profit, load }: Partial<ResourceConfig>): FormGroup {
  return new FormGroup({
    amount: new FormControl(amount || 1),
    profit: new FormControl(profit || 1),
    load: new FormControl(load || 1)
  });
}
```

where no type assertion is necessary, and where the variables in `createResource` are known by the compiler to be `number | undefined`, and where the parameters passed to the `FormControl` constructors are also known to be `number` due to the `|| 1` trick.

---

Another way to deal with this is to actually require that `config` be a `ResourceConfig | undefined`, and assign a valid `ResourceConfig` to it if it's undefined:

```
public addResource(config?: ResourceConfig): void {
  if (!config) {
    config = {
      amount: 1,
      profit: 1,
      load: 1
    };
  }
  const resource: FormGroup = this.createResource(config);
  this.control.push(resource);
}

private createResource({ amount, profit, load }: ResourceConfig): FormGroup {
  return new FormGroup({
    amount: new FormControl(amount),
    profit: new FormControl(profit),
    load: new FormControl(load)
  });
}
```

That freed up `createResource()` from worrying about possible `undefined` variables.  This way might be better if you want to allow `amount`, `profit`, or `load` to be zero.  Note that `0 || 1` is equal to `1`, since `0` is falsy.  If you don't want `0` to turn magically into `1`, you can't use the `|| 1` trick.

---

Anyway either way would work, and many other solutions exist.  The main idea here is to try to take advantage of TypeScript's type system instead of circumventing it.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Wow, did expect such an extensive answer! `Partial` was the concept I was missing, I always used to write to different interfaces. Got a lot to refactor now.
Thanks a lot!